# How to route internet through VPN with Windows Server 2008 R2 on Amazon VPC?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, vpn, privacy

I have a server on Amazon EC2-VPC. I want to connect through VPN to it AND have all my internet traffic routed THROUGH this server, to guarantee my privacy.

I have two network interfaces on the server, one connected to the internet and one on private network.

VPN connections will get an IP address on the private network, and the server will need to act as a NAT to them.

Everything I find on the internet are guides to disable internet going through the VPN. I want it to go through it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What VPN software are you using?

Comment: @NathanC I am using default windows VPN, no additional software necessary (or wanted). I have been able to configure it half-successfully, though I need to set up DNS addresses manually. Will follow with an update on the question if I am able to resolve it.

Comment: were you able to get this done? I am trying to get this set up, could you possibly replay with what your setup was if you were? Thanks! (Cant comment on your original post due to user level)

Comment: @Bajan I have since give up to solve the DNS issues; I have reached a point where it works for my needs. What I needed to do was to first create the connection on the client, then go on the adapter configurations and manually add DNS servers there (I used Google's Public DNS, 8.8.8.8). In the server, what I did was just the default VPN configuration, following the wizards, setting up a NAT, etc. Since this post I have been really busy so no time to post a complete tutorial, but will do this in the other weekend.

Comment: @Bajan A little too late, but I have achieved a fully-working setup using the tutorials on this answer. http://serverfault.com/a/598486/142576

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future lurkers, I have been able to achieve a working setup by using SSTP and a WinServer 2012 Azure VM. These were the tutorials:

Setting up the server

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lighthouse/archive/2013/07/30/how-deploy-sstp-and-l2tp-vpn-in-windows-azure-windows-server-2012.aspx

Setting up Vista/2008 clients

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731352(v=ws.10).aspx